# iOS push notification and avoiding server overload

Tags: ios, notifications, server, push, overloading

My app receives push notification about new data on my server. If user is interested, app downloads new data and displays it.

Imagine app is used by 100 000 users, and everybody receives that push in "the same time" and try to download new data from server - this might cause server overload problem, so I'm thinking how to avoid that?

I thought about making this like that:
- app receives push
- app sets timer with random time (maybe between 1 min - 5min)
- app shows notification after this random time
This way should be lighter for server.
Any other ideas?
Thanks

Comment: 1. Use CDN for images. 2. Convert images to url(or something else like key) 3. apps download images with url from other storage servers.

Comment: Actually there is no images. Just JSON data from my server.

Comment: The theory is same. ^_^

Comment: Any solution to this problem?